# How to return completely empty response in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC Rest controller with one of the URL mappings being :

```
myhost:8080/helloworldexample/testnullresponse
```

Now, is it possible to return nothing at all when I call this URL

Nothing means: no body, no response, no status code simply nothing at all, almost like the server listening to the request did not do anything.

I would appreciate any help on this. I have tried the following options but nothing worked:

```
 return new ResponseEntity<Void>(null);
```

### AND

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/helloworldexample/testnullresponse", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public void nullResponse(HttpServletRequest request) {
        }
```

Comment: even if you find a way, your client will wait for ever, is this what you want?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Yes absolutely.

Comment: In that case, you can use asynchronous responses and just never finish them (though i only know how to do that with jersey). Note, that may need some fiddling to not run out of memory by the server just stock piling response objects

Comment: This is so much burden on the server. I am exhausting useful resources for a URL of the application that is not even doing anything.

Comment: I don't believe that it is even doable since HTTP is a [request-response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request%E2%80%93response) protocol which means that to every request, the corresponding response is expected.

Comment: add @ResponseBoody and you could return a empty string in response or try adding ResponseBody and void method that could also work

Answer (score 0):

Actually your controller's method could return void.
Here is an example

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/helloworldexample/testnullresponse", method = RequestMethod.HEAD)
public void nullResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
...
}
```

Comment: Just a minute, let me try this out.

Comment: It automatically maps it to Bad Request Status code. 
It returns: Status Code: 400 Bad Request

Comment: Did you change the type of request to HEAD?